# Adding objects to array object

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I'm trying to add objects to an existing array if the condition is true.

Below is my code

```
RequestObj = [{
    "parent1": {
        "ob1": value,
        "ob2": {
            "key1": value,
            "key2": value
        },
    },
},
{
    "parent2": {
        "ob1": value,
        "ob2":{
            "key1":value,
            "key2": value
        }
    }
}]
```

Here I'm trying to add an object to the `RequestObj` array if the condition is true. I could do `RequestObj.push()`. But i don't know how to added in `parent1` object.

```
if (key3 !== null) {
    // add this below object to parent1 object
    "ob3": {
        "key1": value,
        "key2": value
    }
}
```

I'm not able to find any solution. Please help

Comment: its an array of objects.. i missed the brackets

Comment: Your brackets are still mismatched

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you want to overwrite the key1 and key2 in a parent1 or parent2 object. Is that correct?

Comment: What is the expected final object you want?

Comment: "parent1": {
         "ob1": value,
         "ob2": {
           "key1": value,
           "key2": value
         },"ob3": {
           "key1": value,
           "key2": value
         }

Comment: i want ob3 to be added inside `parent1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to add an element to an array is to [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) it.

```
// Create new object
var newObject = {
    "ob3": {
        "key1": value,
        "key2": value
    }
};
// Add new object to array
RequestObj.push(newObject);
```

You can also directly push an object into the array without declaring a variable first:

```
// Add new object to array
RequestObj.push({
    "ob3": {
        "key1": value,
        "key2": value
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

If you are not pushing into the  array but adding a new property to an object inside the array, you need to know the position of the element inside the array, like `RequestObj[0]` for the first element.

Then within that element, you need to add a new property to the `parent1` object (`RequestObj[0].parent1`):

```
RequestObj[0].parent1.ob3 = {
      "key1": "A",
      "key2": "B"
 };
```

```js
var RequestObj = [{
  "parent1": {
    "ob1": "A",
    "ob2": {
      "key1": "B",
      "key2": "C"
    },
  },
  "parent2": {
    "ob1": "D",
    "ob2": {
      "key1": "E",
      "key2": "F"
    }
  }
}];

var key3 = 'somethingNotNull';

if (key3 !== null) {
  RequestObj[0].parent1.ob3 = {
      "key1": "A",
      "key2": "B"
  };
}
console.log(RequestObj);
```

Comment: i need to push the ob3 object inside `parent1`.

Comment: every parent 1? or just the first item in the array

Comment: only to parent1, its may not be the first item

Answer (score 0):

You shoud iterate `RequestObj` in loop and find object by key `parent1`.

For that you can use `.filter` function like this:

```
for(let i = 0; i < RequestObj.lenght; i++) {
   let found_object = RequestObj[i].filter(function (r) {
      return r == 'parent1'
   });
}
```

Then you can execute operations over `found_object`.